# Watchdog to monitor node status

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on autonomous quadcopter system and I'm using ROS for my algorithms. What I would like to achieve is to create some watchdogs monitoring all my ROS nodes. I also want it to be able to restart node if it detects it's shutdown (for whatever reason).

But I'm quite lost. Can someone give me an advice or perhaps reference to existing code which does exactly this?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258609/watchdog-to-monitor-node-status/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use a [bond](http://wiki.ros.org/bondpy):

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import rospy
from bondpy import bondpy

def formed():
    print "We got a bond"

def broken():
    print "SOMEONE DIED"

rospy.init_node("A", anonymous=True)
b = bondpy.Bond("heartbeat_topic_name","bond_name", on_broken=broken, on_formed=formed)
b.start()
if not b.wait_until_formed(): 
    raise Exception('Bond could not be formed')

rospy.spin()
```

Just start this node twice, wait for the bond to be established and kill one of the nodes. After a short timeout (4 seconds) the other node will notice the missing partner. With this method, you don't need to poll rosnode list or even know the name of the other node, you just have to use the same topic and bond_name to establish the connection and have a callback triggered as soon as one node does not send its heartbeat anymore.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-06**:
Interesting answer! Didn't know this technique! But how would use bonding with pre-existing nodes?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-04-06**:
So basically if I understand it correctly, if I want to monitor e.g. 10 different nodes I would have to create some watchdog node connected to all of those 10 different nodes with 10 different bonds?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-06**:
To be honest, this code was the first time I used a bond :) But yeah, you can bond exactly two processes, so you will have N bonds.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-04-06**:
Cool, I'll try that option. Thanks

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-06**:
@gstavrinos: you have to change the node, so it won't work with existing nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I want to do something like that, I mainly use two techniques:

- (This is more ROS-formal) Use the respawn="true" roslaunch parameter.

e.g.

```
<node pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="listener" name="listener"  respawn="true" />
```

[You can check the official roslaunch wiki page for more info.](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)

- (This is more hacky, but works like a charm) Use the rosnode command-line tool inside python.

e.g.

```
nodes = os.popen("rosnode list").readlines()
for node in nodes:
    # Make your tests here
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-06**:
Not all nodes are removed from the list when they die, especially if they crash (that's the reason why there is 'rosnode cleanup') A node that is listed in 'rosnode list' does not have to be alive!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it's a bit late to answer this but I found [node_alive](https://github.com/tue-robotics/node_alive) to be very helpful in getting the state of the nodes in the system. It publishes a DiagnosticArray on /diagnostics topic with the information about all the nodes visible to rosmaster and their status.

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-10-04**:
I'll have a look at it, thanks.